# Configuring QCI in LTE for android applications

Tags: android, lte

LTE supports various QoS levels represented by QCI. For e.g. we have QCI 2 for VOIP call, 4 for video call, 3 for online gaming etc. How will android applications express their QOS requirements when they connect to the network ? I am assuming that based on the application category, bearer with corresponding QCI needs to be created by network based on user input.

I understand that for applications like IMS, since we connect to IMS server (probably maintained by network itself), it is possible for network to detect and create a bearer with QCI 1. But for other applications, I think UE/mobile phone need to indicate its QCI requirements ?  Can someone please explain how this works in LTE.

http://4g-lte-world.blogspot.com/2013/01/quality-of-service-qos-in-lte.html

Answer (score 1):

> How will android applications express their QOS requirements when they connect to the network ?

Usually, they don't.

If someone had different experiences, I will be very interested.

Even if the Android APIs allows you to request a specific QoS (and I don't know if this is possible) is unlikely that the mobile operator will accept your request, unless you have some special agreement.

There are two types of *bearers* (aka tunnels for your traffic) between a mobile phone and the network:

- default bearers
- dedicated bearers

The bearer your traffic will flow trough will dictate the QoS.

**Default bearers**

This tunnel is the one owning your ip address, and and at least one is established when you connect to LTE.
More tunnels of this type means that you have many ip addresses.
Each tunnels of maps to an *Access Point Name* (APN) that your device has requested. 
Each APN represents a different network, like a separated LAN;
some APN has access to internet, some other has access to the VOIP network of the operator and some other APN is the network where the operator keeps the MMS servers.
I hope you get it.

The QCI allowed in this type of bearers are from 5 to 9, and the operator knows on which APN you have right to access.
The QOS here is usually allocated during the bearer establishment, according to the APN and data plan, and will be applied for all the data going trough this tunnel until you disconnect.

If you are a very big enterprise (Apple/iphone anyone?) you may ask to the operators to have your dedicated APN and your devices will have some special treatment for the traffic going through this network.

In short, this is not a good place for an App to ask for some specific QOS.

**Dedicated bearers**

This is a tunnel that lives attached to a default bearer.
It act as a filter on the traffic performed on the default bearer it is attached.
To the traffic matching the default bearer filter (ip/port/port-range/protocol) will be applied a QOS different from the one of the default bearer. This is in fact the only way to get a QCI between 1 and 4.
You may have multiple different dedicated bearers attached to your default bearer, and the network is capable to dynamically allocate and remove them upon request.
Since they are quite resource consuming, operators tend to restrict the use of dedicated bearers in number and duration.

There are 4 ways for to trigger the allocation dedicated bearer:

- *Static configuration*: the operator allocate the bearer every time you connect, no matter what. This never used for the dedicated bearer in practice.
- *Device request*: the phone actively request for a dedicated bearer with some specific characteristics. Operators tend to discard this type of request, they prefer to decide by their side when to activate them.
- *Traffic Detection triggered*: the operator monitor your traffic in some way, and if some specific pattern is detected (based on ip/port/protocol/whatever or a combination of these) a dedicated bearer may be allocated.
- *Application Function request*: this is what happens with IMS;
  when you start a call, the SIP server inform the operator about the ongoing call and the operator will allocate a dedicated bearer with QCI 1 for you.

In each case, the request will be evaluated by a node called PCRF. This node is the place where the network check your rights to have specific QoS and/or dedicated bearers.

If there is not a specific rule here that match your application, traffic type, subscription or device, you'll never going to have a QCI between 1 and 4 for your application

**TLDR**

You need a very permissive operator in terms of QoS policies

or

you need some kind of agreement with the operator.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I was curious how device requests for a dedicated bearer. I mean is there a way for an application developer to request for it using android API ? I understand that network may not accept our requests. But I was curious of there is anyway to request in the first place.